# Create a local custom testing environment through Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm currently creating a Minikube cluster for the developers, they will each have their own Minikube cluster in their local machine for testing, assuming the developers don't know anything about Kubernetes, is creating a bash script to handle all the installations and the setup of the pod the recommended way? Is it possible to do it through Terraform instead?Or there's other way to do this easier? Thanks!

Comment: you only need a directory structure of Kubernetes yaml-manifests, then `kubectl apply -f <directory>` unless you talk about installation of Minikube?

Comment: Yes. Also, I'm using ingress, so I have to updated the /etc/hosts file as well

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your requirements are, choosing [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) may or may not be the best way to go.
Just to give you some other options you might want to take a look at the following tools when it comes to local enviornments for developers (depending on their needs):

- [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind)
- [k8s-vagrant-multi-node](https://github.com/galexrt/k8s-vagrant-multi-node)

Since you do not seem to care about Windows or other users (at least they weren't mentioned), a bash script *may* be the simplest way to go. However, usually that's were tools like [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) come into play. They help you with automating things in a clear fashion **and** allow for proper testing. Some tools (like Ansible) even have support for certain Windows features that may be useful.

**TL;DR**

A Bash script is not the recommended way as it has lots of pain points that come with it, however, it may be the fastest approach depending on your skillset.
If you want to do it properly use tools like Ansible, Chef, Puppet, etc.